# Not getting all interrupts in KMDF driver

Tags: c, kmdf

I'm trying to port an existing linux device driver to windows. It's mostly working, but there's a weird issue - sometimes device won't interrupt or the interrupt is lost.
Interrupts are only lost when I'm not actively debugging.

I tried enabling automatic serialization in interrupt config, but this did not resolve my issue.

I'm currently out of options, I suspect either improper synchronization or that I should be using a different wait method.

My ISR looks like this:

```c
  pDE  = xGetDeviceContext(WdfInterruptGetDevice(Interrupt));
  intrv = READ_REG_32(pDE, OFFSET_INTERRUPT_REG);
  pDE->interruptMask = READ_REG_32(pDE, OFFSET_INTERRUPT_MASK_REG);

  intrv &= pDE->interruptMask;
  if(intrv == 0){
      return FALSE;
  }
  pDE->interruptStatus |= intrv; //trying to save values in case different interrupts come too fast for dpc
  WdfInterruptQueueDpcForIsr( pDE->m_Interrupt);
```

DPC:

```c
 pDE  = xGetDeviceContext(WdfInterruptGetDevice(Interrupt));
 WdfInterruptAcquireLock(Interrupt);
 nMainIntStatus = pDE->interruptStatus;
 pDE->interruptStatus = 0;
 WdfInterruptReleaseLock(Interrupt);

 if(nManIntStatus & interrupt_mask_event_1){
   KeSetEvent(&pDE->interrupt_event_1, IO_SOUND_INCREMENT, FALSE);
 }
 //and so on...
```

```c
//In my code I'm waiting on pDE->interrupt_event_1:
 status = KeWaitForSingleObject(&pDE->interrupt_event_1, Executive, KernelMode, TRUE, &timeout);
```

Comment: what is the interval between the successive interrupt event of interest?

Comment: amongst other problems with the posted code, an interrupt handler is executed because the associated interrupt has already occurred.  The ISR needs to perform the processing of the interrupt, then clear the appropriate interrupt flag then perform a `rti` (x86) instruction.  If the code has to go/search for the interrupt, it will miss interrupts, usually because the same interrupt (or a higher priority interrupt) has occurred

Comment: is it MSI or INTA?